# Set minimal JRE version to deb package dependency

Tags: debian, ubuntu, java, packaging, deb

I want to bundle Java application into a .deb package. Inside it is a jar launched with a `java -jar $path/app.jar` script. I need to specify in the package dependencies that it will require JRE >= 11. I've tried 2 options:

- `Depends: java11-runtime` - here the package will be uninstallable because it depends on a virtual package.
- `Depends: default-jre | java11-runtime` - now it will try to install `default-jre` which won't guarantee that it will be at least JRE 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using a versioned dependency on `default-jre`:

```
Depends: default-jre (>= 2:1.11) | java11-runtime
```

If your package doesn’t need the Java GUI packages, it should depend on the `-headless` variants instead.